# Reference separate li selector within ul

Tags: css

I am creating a horizontal navbar and I have an unordered list which I am attempting to style.
I want each list item to display a different color when the button is hovered.
To do this, I am referencing a separate `li` within the main `ul`.
My problem is that I can't seem to reference the `id` called purple within the header `id`.  Any ideas?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title></title>

<style type="text/css">

body {background-color:#EEEEEE}

#header {list-style-type:none; width:978px; height:35px; margin:0 0 25px 0; padding:0}
#header li {float:left; width:100px; height:29px; background:transparent url(images/menu_grad_0.gif) repeat-x; padding:9px 0 0 10px; margin-right:1px}
#header li a {color:#FFFFFF; font-size:13px; font-weight:bold; display:block; text-decoration: none}
#header #purple li a:hover {color:red}

#container {
    background-color: #6c6b6f;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    width: 978px
}

</style>

</head>
<body>

<div id="container">

<ul id="header">
    <li id="purple"><a href="#">&raquo;&nbsp;Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">&raquo;&nbsp;About Me</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">&raquo;&nbsp;Contact</a></li>
</ul>

</div><!--Close DIV Container-->

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Shouldn't it be just...

```
#header #purple a:hover {color:red}
```

Isn't there an extra li in that selector?

Comment: It's also sufficient to use just `#purple a:hover {color:red}` as an ID is unambiguous throughout an HTML document.

Comment: @feeela *should be unambiguous ;p

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to target the first li via the `:first-child` selector - without any `id`s. Like so:

```
#header li:first-child a:hover{
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for something like this id use a class, but you can do it with an id like this:

```
#header li#purple a:hover {color:red}
```

That will do what you want, but I would personally use a class as you might want other things on the page to be "purple"

```
#header li.purple a:hover {color:red}
<li class="purple"><a href="#">&raquo;&nbsp;Home</a></li>
```

Martyn